# What could be the option to implement google recaptcha with current project config

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

The application is based on java 8 , grails 2.4.3, and postgresql. The java based application is using hibernate ORM and spring is embedded.

I have a requirement of implementing google recaptcha enterprise version in the application. We do have google recaptcha implemented with the grails plugin mentioned here https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/iamthechad/recaptcha but same would not be applicable for enterprise version. Because the code inside the plugin seems to be for non enterprise version.
So with the project configuration available what all possible option to implement the recaptcha. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the plugin is being used in the project is very old and does not support enterprise version.

So will have to implement the changes on client and server side for enterprise version and get the migrated keys to use it further for enterprise version